# Select from comma separated list

Tags: php

So I'm working on a tags system, and I have a field that looks like this:

```
<input name="tags" type="text" />
```

And I want a user to be able to type tags like (comma separated): "Tag one, Tag two, Tag Three" and so on, and then in the backend PHP, pull each tag by itself and put them all into an array, such as:

```
$tags = array("Tag one", "Tag two", "Tag three");
```

And then I'm thinking using `foreach` to insert them into their own rows in a database, which I know how to do and all; but I digress. But how do I separate the tags in the string from the user's form input?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with the [explode function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php):

```
$tags = explode(',',$_POST['tags']);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$tags= explode(",", $input_from_tag_form);
```

See more info [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

Answer (score 1):

That is actually pretty simple you just use explode function as many here have point that out on the [PHP Offical Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) you can find pretty good examples on how to use this function

In general you can split using any expression (comma, colon, dashes, or anything you can think of)

```
<?php
$datas = '1213456|Joe|Fake st 405|50678983942|joe@fake.com';

$data_array = explode('|', $datas);

echo "$data_array[0], $data_array[1], $data_array[2], $data_array[3], $data_array[4]";

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `explode()`. It takes in the key by which to separate, and returns an array.

Answer (score 0):

if the submmited url (I assume GET for this purpose) looks like:
yoursite.com?save_tags=abba,music,1970

The code will look like (notice, this is not the full logic):

```
$tags_sql="('" . explode('),(',$_GET['save_tags']) . "')";//this happens after you sanitize input, or just use PDO/MySQLi params to insert the data...google it
$sql = "INSERT INTO tags_table VALUEs {$tags_sql} ON UPDATE SET usage=usage+1";
```

This assumes a tag table with 3 fields, id (pk) |tag_name (unique) |usage(defaults to 1)